# Moving Users Homefolders to Archive after they leave the business

Tags: directory, home-directory

Hi I am not a Scripter but trying to learn.Trying to find out why this script won't work I found it on here but I am unable to identify how to fix the issues it has.

```
PS C:\windows> Param (
    [array]$Users = @(Get-Content "C:\Temp\Users.txt"),
    [string]$oldserver = srvmanfiler
    [string]$Newserver = SrvmanArchive
)

$Users | ForEach { Robocopy "\\$oldserver\Users\Homedrives\$_" "\\$newserver\Archive\\Homedrives\" /COPY:DAT /v }
```

At line:3 char:22
+     [string]$oldserver = srvmanfiler
+                         ~
Missing expression after '='.
At line:3 char:20
+     [string]$oldserver = srvmanfiler
+                       ~
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At line:5 char:1
+ )
+ ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

PS C:\windows> `enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it now does what I require which is Move the folders using SamAccount Names to the Destination the full syntax is :

```
Param (
    [array]$Users = @(Get-Content "C:\Temp\Aliases.txt"),
    [string]$oldserver = "srvmanFiler",
    [string]$Newserver = "SrvmanArchive"
)

$Users | ForEach { Robocopy "\\$oldserver\Users\Homedrives\$_" "\\$newserver\Archive\\Homedrives\$_" /COPY:DAT /E  /Move  /V }
```